# Write the content into the batch file

Tags: php, batch-file, logging

I want to create a log file in my local system after running a batch file by setting a cronjob on my Windows machine.

As of now I'm displaying the contents in the console when the cronjob is executed - the same content I want to save in the form of log.

Note: I've tried syslog but it's not working. I have imported the index.php in the batch file.

Comment: hi @npocmaka will go through it Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm confused... what does php have to do with saving the output of a batch program to a file?

Comment: @ Jeff Bridgman as i mentioned above in note I'm importing. The php file In batch file and displaying the output statement of that in log file so I have tagged php that's all there is no need to get confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check dbenham implementation of tee command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21841567/388389).
You can output to the console like:

```
call batfile.bat  | batchTee log.txt
```

Comment: Im trying it now and may i know where will the log file stored

Comment: @happy  in the example above it should be in the execution directory (`log.txt`).But I think you can set a full path if you want.

Comment: @ npocmaka   when I run the batch file Im getting output in log.txt User: C:\wamp\www\Fed\index1.php - April 24, 2015, 8:53 am
Attempt: Failed
User: 
Pass: 
-------------------------
User: C:\wamp\www\Fed\index1.php - April 24, 2015, 9:12 am
Attempt: Failed
User: 
Pass: 
-------------------------
User: C:\wamp\www\Fed\index1.php - April 24, 2015, 9:15 am
Attempt: Failed
User: 
Pass: 
-------------------------
Please can you give a example where can i specify the full path.